# Setting the file name returned by ASP .NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to set the name of the file that is being returned by the ASP .NET WEB API. Currently its just returns in the name of the parameters that is being passed in the URL. But what if I need then to be returned as ABC.JSON

```
public class NewTestController : ApiController
{
public string Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
{using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=J;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T"))
    {
        var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
        var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var strQuery = @"SELECT 
                       * from STPR_STUDY where STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN (" + srtcon + ")";
        OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
        DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(selectResults);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
}}}
```

I did see in other forums using Content-Disposition but I am not using HTTPResponse in code. How can this be done. Thanks

I tried like below

```
 OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new     OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
            DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(selectResults);
            string result =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            response.Content = new StreamContent(result);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Abc.JSON"
            };
     return(result);
```

But it throws the error in StreamContent saying,the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments  in StreamConent

Comment: You returning `string` from your controller. You should use at least `IHttpActionResult`, but better `HttpResponseMessage` to set your file name

Comment: Teo van kot, I tried using HTTPResponseMessageand I am getting error in the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments in StreamConent. I am creating my first Web API

Comment: Returning serialized DataTable doesn't make sense from API, What is the end result you are hoping to get at the client side?

Comment: I want them to be JSON in response. I am converting from DataTable to the JSON  using JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CreateResponse method of Request object like below

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        string fileName = "abc.json";
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileName);
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

```
   string contentDisposition = "inline; filename=abc.json";
   HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, byteInfo, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
   response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(contentDisposition);
   return response;
```

Comment: But I am converting the DataTable in to the JSON. So wont I be returning them in the String. I am sorry, I am new and little stuck.

Comment: Even if it is string you should use HttpResponseMessage to return data to client. if you need help on, how to use it on the client side let me know

Comment: 'DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(selectResults);
                string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectResults);
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                var fileName = "abc.json";
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileName);'  I tried this code and it opes the file as NewTest.JSOn with data inside as ABC.JSON. It doesnot return the original data

Comment: Oh ok I thought you only wanted to return the filename. I have modified my answer based on your above comment. Let me know if that works

Comment: Yes I tried using the above code like I showed in my comment. It opens a file as NewTest.Json(which is name of the controller of the Web API application) but if I open it inside it has data as abc.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118243/discussion-between-paresh-and-trx).